# Right pattern to use to parse 2020-02-29T18:21:13.2627230Z using SimpleDateFormat Class

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have this date/time value `2020-02-29T18:21:13.2627230Z` that I am trying to parse using SimpleDateFormat Class. I used several patterns because I don't which to use:

`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'` => Time parsed is: Sat Feb 29 19:05:00 UTC 2020

`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssss` => Time parsed is: Sat Feb 29 18:21:13 UTC 2020

`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS` => Time parsed is: Sat Feb 29 19:05:00 UTC 2020

What does the last part mean `2627230Z`. Are the digits here the milliseconds and `Z`  the time in UTC? if so, shouldn't I use the pattern that ends with `SSSSSSSZ` ? I'm getting a parseException here.

Also why am I getting a different output in the minutes `19:05:00` (1st pattern) and `18:21:13` (2nd pattern)

Thanks

Comment: The other answers have already mentioned it. Use `java.time`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) from the [java::time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package. You can then further modify it by changing zones or time offsets.  The other date packaged like `Date` and `Calendar` are obsolete.

```
    String s = "2020-02-29T18:21:13.2627230Z";
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(s);
        System.out.println(zdt);
```

Prints

```
2020-02-29T18:21:13.262723Z
```

To find out what those values mean and others, check out the [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.  It explains everything you want to know.

Answer (score 1):

The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. I suggest you should stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

**Using the modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.parse("2020-02-29T18:21:13.2627230Z");
        System.out.println(instant);

        System.out.println(instant.getNano());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-02-29T18:21:13.262723Z
262723000
```

> What does the last part mean 2627230Z. Are the digits here the
> milliseconds and Z the time in UTC?

It is nanoseconds and `Z` stands for Zulu i.e. date-time at UTC.